# When I'm trying to remove items from the listview using provider it removed last element from the list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

When I'm trying to remove `item(like 0 index item)` from this `listview` using provider it removed the last item from the list. while I'm deleting last element from the list successfully remove last item. I'm bit confusing why this kind of problem is happening to me.

Here I'm posting some code please check give your valuable suggestion. Also demonstrate on this video what issue is happening

Link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UYl8Z7vEj_tZCaYzqe0VqZL2iMla5nIZ/view?usp=sharing

**Expected result:** Whenever user press delete button then delete that particular row(item).

**Delete method:-** This is the delete method It'll be call when user press delete button from the list.

```
Future<void> acceptdeclinerequest(String requestStatus,int requestId) async{
    String token = await CustomPreferences.getpreferences('token');
    Map<String, String> requestHeaders;
    if (token.isNotEmpty) {
      requestHeaders = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      };
    } else {
      requestHeaders = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      };
    }
    var reqdata = {
      "request_id":requestId.toString(),
      "status":requestStatus
    };
    print('accept request data is $reqdata');
    try
    {
      final response =
      await http.post(Connection.url + 'respond-place-request', headers: requestHeaders,body: reqdata);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
        final existingProductIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == requestId);
        var existingProduct = _items[existingProductIndex];
        _items.removeAt(existingProductIndex);
        notifyListeners();
        return responseJson;
      } /*else if (response.statusCode == 500) {
        return servererrorresponse;
      }*/
    } catch (exception) {
      throw exception;
    }
  }
```

**Main Widget class:** This is the main widget class where I define `Listview` widget. I've used provider to get data from api which is written in modal class to populate in `Listview` and `Listview child widgets` is in seprate class which is `RequestWidgets`. In this class I've passed `rowitems` data to show in `listview`.

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  var connectionstatus;
  var product;
  var _isInit = true;
  var _isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    if (_isInit) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      Provider.of<BandRequestModal>(context).getBandRequestList().then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      });
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    connectionstatus = Provider.of<ConnectivityResult>(context);
    product = Provider.of<BandRequestModal>(context, listen: false);
    // getRequestData();
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _onWillPop,
        child: Scaffold(
            key: _scaffoldKey,
            appBar: CustomAppbar(
                _scaffoldKey, Constants.requests, 100.0, filterRecord),
            endDrawer: MenuDrawer(),
            body:
                /*(connectionstatus == ConnectivityResult.wifi ||
                    connectionstatus == ConnectivityResult.mobile)
                ? */
                Consumer<BandRequestModal>(builder: (context, modal, child) {
              return !_isLoading
                  ? Container(child: LayoutBuilder(builder:
                      (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                      return Container(
                        height: constraints.maxHeight,
                        child: modal.item.length > 0
                            ? ListView.builder(
                                padding:
                                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 0.0),
                                itemCount: modal.item.length,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
//                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                itemBuilder: (context, int i) {
                                  return RequestWidgets(data: modal.item[i]);
                                })
                            : Center(
                                child: new Text(
                                  Constants.norecordfound,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                              ),

//                    ],
//                  ),
                      );
                    }))
                  : Comman.loadingIndicator(Theme.of(context).primaryColor);
            })
//                : Comman.nointernetconnection(context)
//            FutureBuilder<BandRequestModal>(
//                future: Connection.bandRequestList(),
//                builder: (context, snapshot) {
//                  switch (snapshot.connectionState)
//                  {
//                    case ConnectionState.none:
//                      break;
//                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
//                      return Comman.loadingIndicator(
//                          Theme.of(context).primaryColor);
//                      break;
//                    case ConnectionState.active:
//                      break;
//                    case ConnectionState.done:
//                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
//                        return Center(
//                          child: new Text(Constants.servererror),
//                        );
//                      }else if(snapshot.data==null){
//                        return Center(
//                          child: new Text(Constants.servererror),
//                        );
//                      } else if (snapshot.data.data.length == 0) {
//                        return Center(
//                          child: new Text(
//                            Constants.norecordfound,
//                            style: TextStyle(
//                                fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
//                          ),
//                        );
//                      } else {
//                        return ListView.builder(
//                            padding:
//                            EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 60.0),
//                            itemCount: snapshot.data.data.length,
//                            shrinkWrap: true,
//                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
//                            itemBuilder: (context, int i) {
//                              return RequestWidgets(data:snapshot.data.data[i]);
//                            });
//                      }
//                      break;
//                  }
//                }):Comman.nointernetconnection(context)
            ));
  }
```

**Child widget class:** This is the row items class of listview In this class we used many widgets to show place data.

```
class _RequestWidgetsState extends State<RequestWidgets> {
  var getData;
  var product;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    getData = widget.data;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    product = Provider.of<BandRequestModal>(context, listen: false);
    return Container(
//      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
      child: ListTile(
//        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        key: ObjectKey(getData),
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 30,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          child: ClipOval(
              child: (getData.placeDetails.image != null &&
                      getData.placeDetails.image != '')
                  ? Image.network(
                      getData.placeDetails.image,
                      width: 90,
                      height: 90,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )
                  : Image.asset(
                      Res.defaultImage,
                      width: 90,
                      height: 90,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )),
        ),
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: Text(getData.placeDetails.name,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontFamily: 'Metropolis',
                        color: CustomColors.commentTitleColor))),
          ],
        ),
        subtitle: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0),
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0),
                child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      child: Text(getData.placeDetails.address,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              height: 1.2,
                              fontFamily: 'Metropolis',
                              color: CustomColors.commentSubtitleColor))),
                ]),
              ),
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[],
                  )),
              Divider(
                color: CustomColors.commentlineColor,
                thickness: 0.8,
              )
            ])),
        trailing: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 20,
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.check,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                acceptrejectpopup('1');

//                {
//                  print('accept data $data');
//                  Comman.hideLoading(context);
//                  Comman.showSnakBar(data['message'],context);
//                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 15.0,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.clear,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {
//                Comman.showLoading(context);
                acceptrejectpopup('0');
                /*product.acceptdeclinerequest('0',getData.id.toString()).then((data){
                  print('decline data $data');
                  Comman.hideLoading(context);
                  Comman.showSnakBar(data['message'],context);
                });*/
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  //accept and reject
  void acceptRejectRequest(String requestStatus) async {
    try {
      var response =
          await product.acceptdeclinerequest(requestStatus, getData.id);
      if (response['status'] == Constants.status_true) {
        Comman.hideLoading(context);
        Comman.showSnakBar(response['message'], context);
//        setState(() {});
      } else {
        Comman.hideLoading(context);
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      Comman.hideLoading(context);
      Comman.showSnakBar(Constants.servererror, context);
    }
  }

  //request accept/reject popup
  Future<void> acceptrejectpopup(String reqStatus) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Alert!',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        content: new Text(reqStatus == '1'
            ? Constants.reqAcceptmessage
            : Constants.reqRejectemessage),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            child: new Text(Constants.notxt),
          ),
          new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Comman.showLoading(context);
              acceptRejectRequest(reqStatus);
            },
            child: new Text(Constants.yestxt),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The provider is working just fine, the problem is when the provider notify the consumer the `ListView` updates the children, but the `StatefulWidget` check they're the same type (They're all `RequestWidget`) so they just update themselves (if you don't provide a key to the `StatefulWidget` they will try to check if they're the same element and update via the `didChangeDependencies` method), but you're updating the `getData` var in initState (which will call only once) so even if the consumer updates the value won't. Try it like this

```
@override
void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  //getData = widget.data; not here
  super.initState();
}

@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  getData = widget.data; //update it here
  super.didChangeDependencies();
}
```

Other option would be just to give a specific key when building your widget in the itemBuilder so when the consumer updates it changes them accordingly

```
return RequestWidgets(key: ValueKey(modal.item[i].id),data: modal.item[i]);

// Or some value unique for each item
```

Comment: hey man thank you for reply and think is issue resolved thank alot man you saved my alot of time.can you do me favour can you elaborate more this issue for knowlege.

Comment: I answer a similar question here with a full explanation that may help you understand what is happening https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699351/flutter-the-index-value-i-asked-to-remove-is-different-from-the-index-value-tha/61705770#61705770

Answer (score 1):

The problem here I guess is, in your `Child widget class`, since I can't see any `requestId` of the selected card being passed to the `acceptdeclinerequest()`.

Your `acceptdeclinerequest()` expects two unique arguments to be passed when called:

- `String requestStatus`
- `int requestId`

If you look closely into the **Child widget class**, you are just passing `requestStatus`. I wonder from where are you getting this `getData.id`, and how is it identifying that some particular card is selected.

```
// look here, only requestStatus is being passed
onTap: () {
    acceptrejectpopup('0');
 }

// and here
onTap: () {
   acceptrejectpopup('1');
}
```

And in your `acceptRejectRequest`, you are only passing `requestStatus`

```
acceptRejectRequest(reqStatus);
```

And then you call your `acceptdeclinerequest()` with this data

```
// machine is confused, where are we getting the getData.id
// it assumes the id as per it's need, hence the error
await product.acceptdeclinerequest(requestStatus, getData.id);
```

The machine is trying to figure out, which element you selected. Try to give the id from the selected card, and pass it to the method with correct `getData.id` of that particular element.

**Suggestion:** Pass in your `id` of the selected card when you are tapping on it, and then call your methods, and then pass it along to get the right `requestId` and remove it. Let your methods `acceptrejectpopup()` and `acceptRejectRequest()` accept the `id` of the selected item and then finally pass it to your `acceptdeclinerequest()`

```
// first step
onTap: () => acceptrejectpopup('0', your_card_reuqest_id);

// second step, pass data from the above popup method to acceptRejectRequest()
acceptRejectRequest(reqStatus, requestId);

//finally from acceptRejectRequest(reqStatus, requestId), pass it to the final method acceptdeclinerequest
acceptdeclinerequest(requestStatus, requestId);
```

Comment: thank for your reply As you say pass the reqid key I passed but issue not resolved.please check this screenshot https://prnt.sc/tt1yjh.previously I checked using debug request id is going correct

Comment: Great start @SumitKumawat So now can you please tell me if you are getting the right index when you do `print(existingProductIndex);` inside you `acceptdeclinerequest()`? The idea to ensure, that you are removing the correct item and when it will rebuild it will surely show the right result

Comment: Thanks but issue resolved i changed this line RequestWidgets(data: modal.item[i]); to RequestWidgets(key: ValueKey(modal.item[i].id),data: modal.item[i]);

Comment: Great @SumitKumawat. You mark **EdwynZN** as correct answer, which will allow the upcoming people to find the correct result only. Go ahead and do that. Glad you got it working :)